# How do I change stdin Stream with Eclipse run command?

Tags: linux, eclipse, command-line, command

I'm working on a project where rather than using command line arguments I am supposed to just pipe a file to stdin and pipe output to another file.

ie I need to run something like:

```
./program < infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

Is there a way to specify to Eclipse this is the command I want when it is run?

I am running the Eclipse-C/C++ environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using Eclipse for some time, it seems like there is not a straightforward way of doing this. I've resorted to just adding debug code to specify a file and then declare it as an input stream.